# MacBook Internet Recovery "?" Folder

Tags: macbook-pro, install, startup

With my 2012 MacBook Pro, I'm trying to reinstall Mac OS X (any version that will work) onto a new Solid State Drive that replaced a broken one. I can get to the Internet Recovery screen just fine when directly connected to the Internet (ethernet). The problem lies AFTER the Internet Recovery installation succeeds.

There really isn't a good way to describe what happens because the laptop seems to be trying to decide whether or not there is a problem or not. Here is a link to a YouTube video I've uploaded of the problem:

[YouTube Video of Problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQO2tcEZyZc&list=UUYVws-28G0fFvDgnFiGfqoQ)

After this happens for a while, it resolves to just the blinking "?" Folder Icon.

I do not have access to another Mac computer.

Comment: trying to watch the movie :)

Comment: It's really short. If, for some reason, you can't see the video, it's basically flickering in between the "circle cross", the "? folder" and the "Apple logo".

Comment: ok, saw it :), try booting in safe mode or Verbose mode. The Internet Recovery did not do a good job, as you know your boot sector is broken. Maybe you have to redo the cmd-r.

Comment: I booted into Verbose, and it stopped on "error loading kernel cache". It then went to the blinking "? folder" screen.

Comment: So we need to try another Internet Install with cmd-r

Comment: I've redone the internet install 10 times now. I think it's a problem with the cable that connects the SSD to the logic board. Gonna have to get that replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your machine boots to Internet Recovery successfully, you will have the option to choose Utilities - go into Disk Utility and verify/repair/partition the new drive.

If the machine cannot successfully boot to internet recovery then you have isolated the issue to one of two things:

- The network isn't reliable enough to download the boot image and utilities
- The hardware itself isn't healthy enough to run the known good system loaded from the internet

The fix for the former is choose a different network. The latter will need a technician to troubleshoot the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The '?' generally means that the system is not able to detect a properly-formatted hard drive. If your SSD is new, your will need to format it to `Mac OS Extended Journaled` using disk-utility.

Here is the link that will help your through most of this stuff.

http://mashable.com/2014/10/17/clean-install-os-x-yosemite/